# ListView items reordering and repeating using baseadapter

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview, android-listview

I am trying to implement a listview that displays a list of directories. and under each directory is a gridview with associated adapter (shown below) showing a list of image thumbnails (see below image). I have it working great except whenever the list item is off the screen then brought back on screen, the images are reloaded. I am using an asynctask to download the thumbnails and replace the placeholder image for each imageview so it is not acceptable that everytime an item is offscreen, all of its thumbnails are downloaded again. Does anyone have an example of this type of implementation (gridview adapter within a listview adapter) where the imageview (or images) are stored? What is the proper way to do this?
Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: Screenshot of Activity]

### Gallery Adapter

```java
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
ArrayList<GalleryItem> GalleryList;
//MediaAdapter adapter;


public GalleryAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<GalleryItem> l) {
    mContext = c;
    GalleryList = l;
}

public int getCount() {
    return GalleryList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return GalleryList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GalleryViewHolder viewHolder = null;


    if(convertView==null){
        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new GalleryViewHolder();
        viewHolder.title =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.folder_settings = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.folder_settings);
        viewHolder.mediaGrid = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagegrid);
        viewHolder.gridHolder = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridholder);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (GalleryViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



    viewHolder.title.setText(GalleryList.get(position).getTitle());
//Formatting the gridView to fit the screen dim.
    ImageTools mWidth = new ImageTools(mContext);
    viewHolder.mediaGrid.setColumnWidth(mWidth.imageSize());
    int rows = (int) Math.ceil((GalleryList.get(position).getMedia().size() / mWidth.columnNumber)+1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, mWidth.imageSize()*rows);
    viewHolder.gridHolder.setLayoutParams(labelLayoutParams);
    viewHolder.mediaGrid.setLayoutParams(labelLayoutParams);
    viewHolder.mediaGrid.setMinimumHeight(mWidth.imageSize()*rows);
//Set Adapter for image views
    viewHolder.mediaGrid.setAdapter(new MediaAdapter(convertView.getContext(),GalleryList.get(position).getMedia()));

    viewHolder.folder_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialogs.createListDialog(mContext,"Folder Actions", R.array.gallery_action_array).show();
        }
    });

    viewHolder.mediaGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private class GalleryViewHolder {
    private TextView title;
    private ArrayList<ImageView> imageList;
    private GridView mediaGrid;
    private ImageView folder_settings;
    private LinearLayout gridHolder;
    private int position;
}
}
```

### Media Adapter

```java
public class MediaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
ArrayList<MediaItem> mediaitems;

public MediaAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<MediaItem> l) {
    mContext = c;
    mediaitems = l;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mediaitems.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mediaitems.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);

        imageView.setTag(R.integer.path,mediaitems.get(position).getPath().toString());
        imageView.setTag(R.integer.fullsize,"false");
        imageView.setTag(R.integer.parentpath,mediaitems.get(position).getParentPath().toString());
        imageView.setTag(R.integer.index , String.valueOf(position));
        try {
            new thumbDownload(mContext).execute(imageView);
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ImageTools mWidth = new ImageTools(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mWidth.imageSize(), mWidth.imageSize()));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    //imageView.setImageBitmap(mediaitems.get(position).getBitmap());
    return imageView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up Using a `HashMap<String,Bitmap>` to store the images once they were downloaded. I made the hashMap static in my mediaAdapter so I could add the bitmap from my asynctask when it was downloaded.  Then in my media Adapter `getView()`, I added a if statement to check if the image had already been downloaded. If it had, I used `setImageBitmap(myHash.get(key))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..may be its silly way, but its worked for me. Just add a line of code inside your method like this for gallery adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
GalleryViewHolder viewHolder = null;  
// Add this line.
convertView = null;

if(convertView==null){
    // inflate the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new GalleryViewHolder();
    viewHolder.title =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    viewHolder.folder_settings = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.folder_settings);
    viewHolder.mediaGrid = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagegrid);
    viewHolder.gridHolder = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridholder);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
}
else{
    viewHolder = (GalleryViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

// rest of your code

}
```

Comment: T-Rush, This just keeps the adapters from reusing views. Which I actually want to reuse the views. Anyway, I tried it and it is still loading the images every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) to implement your UI and [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for flexible asynchronous image loading.

> StickyGridHeaders is an Android library that provides a GridView that shows items in sections with headers. By default the section headers stick to the top like the People app in Android 4.x but this can be turned off.
>
> Android-Universal-Image-Loader aims to provide a reusable instrument for asynchronous image loading, caching and displaying.